# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 - Infinite-like boot

Tags: boot, server, filesystem

I have a very long boot time on my Ubuntu Server machine, used just for Zimbra mail server.

I don't have much experience on file systems (none), and since the server is remote (housing, with only ssh access), I wouldn't want to do irreparable damage.

So, despite a lot of research before posting this question, I ask you.

Below I inform you as much information as possible

This is release info

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

My `dmseg` (at the "hot" point)

```
[   13.483425] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
[   13.483428] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
[   15.208227] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up
[  299.864155] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[  322.367057] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[  323.270765] ipmi message handler version 39.2
[  323.306618] IPMI System Interface driver.
[  323.306657] ipmi_si: Adding default-specified kcs state machine
[  323.306663] ipmi_si: Trying default-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
[  323.306673] ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
[  323.325508] ipmi_si: Adding default-specified smic state machine
[  323.325537] ipmi_si: Trying default-specified smic state machine at i/o address 0xca9, slave address 0x0, irq 0
[  323.325551] ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
[  323.337949] ipmi_si: Adding default-specified bt state machine
[  323.337959] ipmi_si: Trying default-specified bt state machine at i/o address 0xe4, slave address 0x0, irq 0
[  323.337975] ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
[  323.366265] ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
[  324.297495] audit_printk_skb: 12 callbacks suppressed
[  324.297502] audit: type=1400 audit(1556873113.607:16): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1355/status" pid=1355 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=108 ouid=108
[  324.297578] audit: type=1400 audit(1556873113.607:17): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1355 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=108 ouid=0
[  324.297681] audit: type=1400 audit(1556873113.607:18): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1355/status" pid=1355 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=108 ouid=108
[ 2351.028248] perf interrupt took too long (2511 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

the heart of the problem lies here...

```
[  299.864155] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[  322.367057] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

...and here

```
[ 2351.028248] perf interrupt took too long (2511 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

It is clear that, at least in the first case, this is some devilish thing about the filesystem

Here my `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
graphical.target @8min 12.557s
└─multi-user.target @8min 12.557s
  └─zimbra.service @5min 17.228s +2min 55.328s
    └─cron.service @5min 17.225s
      └─basic.target @5min 16.399s
        └─sockets.target @5min 16.399s
          └─snapd.socket @5min 16.396s +1ms
            └─sysinit.target @5min 16.344s
              └─systemd-update-utmp.service @5min 16.285s +55ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @6.628s +5min 9.643s
                  └─local-fs.target @6.601s
                    └─run-user-999.mount @5min 17.509s
                      └─local-fs-pre.target @3.439s
                        └─systemd-remount-fs.service @3.365s +57ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @1.507s
                            └─-.mount @1.470s
                              └─system.slice @1.505s
                                └─-.slice @1.470s
```

For "weight" reasons, we must exclude the `zimbra.service` , since being a fairly heavy software, it is reasonable to assume that it takes a long time to boot.

I am going then to analyze this `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @6.628s +5min 9.643s`, and doing a Google search, I go back to several results that talk about the filesystem.

So here my `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="6f78f8e3-eb96-40ab-9fcf-83efe036ed85" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="bf518064-20ce-4355-8c91-6f2c7bfb0a09"
/dev/sda3: UUID="43d915cf-4be9-4930-b0cc-8b17856d7940" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="34b75fdd-36e0-4620-bdb4-5073d25a1397"
/dev/sda4: TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="b35559dd-07ee-46d9-aea5-addd0aa16c51"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="1b8c2ffe-1ef7-481c-a479-b0b72611a377"
```

and my `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
/dev/sda3 /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
/dev/sda2 /boot           ext3    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
/dev/sda4 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I have a little note to make. For reasons of space I had to delete the old releases, otherwise I could not make any apt-get install. I don't know if this caused the problem, but it was the only major operation I performed on the system.

However, I'm not interested in the "cooked and eaten" solution, also because I can't afford to do tests.
Instead, I'm interested in understanding what, based on the information provided, causes this near-infinite boot

Thanks

===============================================

**EDIT**

As suggested by heynnema, here results of `grep -i -B 10 -A 10 mce /var/log/syslog*`

```
    /var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030147] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030151] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030156] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030164] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030168] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030243] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail systemd[1]: Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030246] CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.030253] FEATURE SPEC_CTRL Not Present
/var/log/syslog:May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.042007] mce: CPU supports 7 MCE banks
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.042085] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.042133] process: using mwait in idle threads
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.042139] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 48, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.042141] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 0
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.042145] Spectre V2 mitigation: Mitigation: Full generic retpoline
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.042148] Spectre V2 mitigation: Speculation control IBPB not-supported IBRS not-supported
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.044907] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.058017] ftrace: allocating 32202 entries in 126 pages
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [    0.135915] smpboot: APIC(0) Converting physical 0 to logical package 0
--
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.135896] audit: type=1400 audit(1556872802.974:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-mounting" pid=889 comm="apparmor_parser"
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.135905] audit: type=1400 audit(1556872802.974:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=889 comm="apparmor_parser"
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.139747] audit: type=1400 audit(1556872802.978:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=893 comm="apparmor_parser"
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.139768] audit: type=1400 audit(1556872802.978:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=893 comm="apparmor_parser"
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.148187] audit: type=1400 audit(1556872802.986:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lxd/lxd-bridge-proxy" pid=892 comm="apparmor_parser"
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.151918] audit: type=1400 audit(1556872802.990:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=896 comm="apparmor_parser"
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.194174] audit: type=1400 audit(1556872803.034:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=894 comm="apparmor_parser"
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.483425] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   13.483428] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [   15.208227] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up
/var/log/syslog:May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [  299.864155] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:11 webmail kernel: [  322.367057] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail dnsmasq[1085]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail dbus[1133]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail systemd[1]: Starting LSB: OpenIPMI Driver init script...
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Zimbra mail service...
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail cron[1157]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail systemd[1]: Starting LSB: MD monitoring daemon...
/var/log/syslog-May  3 10:45:12 webmail systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Binary file /var/log/syslog.5.gz matches
```

Comment: I can't help with your problem, but 16.04.4 came out 3-March-2018, so your system software is out-of-date (before that date), as you should be running 16.04.6, so I would suggest `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` to bring your software up-to-date for security, plus it may help.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about the mce error. Lets see if syslog can provide more information. `grep -i -B 10 -A 10 mce /var/log/syslog*`. Edit your question and copy/paste that output, or put it on paste.ubuntu.com. Report back. (also... side note... your fstab should use UUID's instead of /dev/sdaN, but we'll talk about that later.)

Comment: @heynnema as you suggested, I edited the post adding the information you requested. Many thanks

Comment: @guiverc I believe your suggestion is the basis of good server administration behavior. However, such an important update, on a remote machine, to put it simply, scares me

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm mostly concerned about the mce error. The syslog (thanks) did provide a whole lot on enlightenment. Without manually reviewing the entire log, I don't have enough info to go on. I am confused about the superblock notation, and that your `blkid` looks strange. 1. are you able to work with the server at the console level to run `fsck` tests on your disk, and memory diagnostics? 2. Does the machine otherwise seem to operate once fully booted? 3. Any further clues to help me diagnose the problem for you?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. Yes 
3. no, at the moment

Comment: @heynnema UPDATES: after apt-get autoremove, inexplicably, boot in 10 seconds

Comment: @OscarZarrus Don't know why that would have helped, but I guess that we'll call it case closed for now.